# How to specify a WCF known type in config that is generic?

Tags: .net, wcf, generics, known-types

I have a type, let's call it `Data<TKey>`.  I also have a WCF service contract that accepts a type (lets call it `Wrapper`) with a property of type `Object` (for reasons I won't go into, this isn't optional).

```
[DataContract]
public class Data<TKey> { ... }

[DataContract]
public class Wrapper
{
    [DataMember]
    public object DataItem { get; set; }
}
```

Right now I'm sending two classes `IntData` and `LongData`:

```
[DataContract]
public class IntData : Data<int> { /*empty*/ }

[DataContract]
public class LongData : Data<long> { /*empty*/ }
```

They're both configured in the known types config file.  The config resembles something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
      <declaredTypes>
        <add type="Wrapper, TheirAssembly">
          <knownType type="IntData, MyAssembly"/>
          <knownType type="LongData, MyAssembly"/>
        </add>
      </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
  </system.runtime.serialization>
</configuration>
```

At this point, everything works fine.

But I'm about to add a third type and I don't like having the unnecessary, empty .NET classes `IntData` and `LongData`.  They only exist because...

*I don't know how to specify generic types in WCF configuration!*

I want to do something like this, but don't know the exact syntax.

```
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
      <declaredTypes>
        <add type="Wrapper, TheirAssembly">
          <!-- this syntax is wrong -->
          <knownType type="Data{System.Int32}, MyAssembly"/>
          <knownType type="Data{System.Int64}, MyAssembly"/>
        </add>
      </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
  </system.runtime.serialization>
</configuration>
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

(Note too that I cannot put `[KnownType(...)]` attributes on `Wrapper` as it's not my type.  Config seems to be the only way.)

**EDIT**

@baretta's answer worked nicely.  Note however that initially I received this error:

> Type 'MyAssembly.Data`1[System.Int64]' cannot be added to list of known types since another type 'MyAssembly.Data`1[System.Int32]' with the same data contract name 'http://www.mycompany.com/MyAssembly:Data' is already present.

I didn't mention it in the original question, but my type has an explicit data contract name.  Something like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Data")]
public class Data<TKey> { ... }
```

The above error occurred until I removed the `Name` property value from the attribute.  Hope that helps someone else out too.  I don't know what format works in this scenario.  These didn't:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Data\`1")]
[DataContract(Name = "Data{TKey}")]
```

Anyone know how to do this?

**EDIT 2**

Thanks again to @baretta who pointed out that the correct syntax is in fact:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Data{0}")]
```

Comment: Yeah, I know! :) I edited my answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A generic type is instantiable from a string, if the string follows this pattern:
*Class name followed by a "`" character, followed by the number of type parameters(in this case it's 1), followed by the type parameters enclosed within "[]", and using comma as type parameter separator*.

```
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
      <declaredTypes>
        <add type="Wrapper, TheirAssembly">
          <!-- this syntax is all good -->
          <knownType type="Data`1[System.Int32], MyAssembly"/>
          <knownType type="Data`1[System.Int64], MyAssembly"/>
        </add>
      </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
  </system.runtime.serialization>
</configuration>
```

Edit: I might also add, that if assembly information needs to be specified for the type parameters(althoug it's not the case for stuff in mscorlib), then nested "[]" is used.

```
<knownType type="Data`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]], MyAssembly"/>
```

Edit: You can customize names of generic types in data contracts, using the string format pattern.

```
[DataContract(Name = "Data{0}")]
public class Data<TKey>
{...}
```

By default, the name generated for the Data<Int32> type is something like "DataOfInt32HJ67AK7Y", where "HJ67AK7Y"
is a hash generated from the string "urn:default", or the namespace of your class, if you have any. But "Data{0}" would give it the name "DataInt32".

More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045.aspx). Have a look at the "Customizing Data Contract Names for Generic Types" part down the page.

Comment: Thanks Baretta.  This concise answer worked perfectly, once I sorted out the issue with the name attribute (see my edit).

Comment: Thanks for your edit.  This is a great answer and if I could vote for it twice, I would :)

Comment: A little tip, when going down this path make sure the Type being registered is public.  It was certainly a face palm moment when we realized why this solution did not work "out of the box"

Answer (score 5):

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sowmy/archive/2006/06/06/618877.aspx)...

> Known
>   types can also be defined in config as
>   shown below.

```
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
      <declaredTypes>
         <add type="MyCompany.Library.Shape`1,
              MyAssembly, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
              PublicKeyToken=XXXXXX, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
            <knownType type="MyCompany.Library.Circle`1,
                       MyAssembly, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                       PublicKeyToken=XXXXXX, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
                    <parameter index="0"/>
            </knownType>
         </add>
      </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
  </system.runtime.serialization>
</configuration>
```

> The above config specifies that the
>   generic parameter for Circle is the
>   same as the generic parameter for the
>   declared type Shape. The config allows
>   the definition of known type of
>   arbitrary complexity. For example if
>   it is needed to define
>   Circle< Dictionary< string, T >> as the
>   known type of Shape< T > (of course this
>   is purely academic) it can be done as
>   follows.

```
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
      <declaredTypes>
         <add type="MyCompany.Library.Shape`1,
              MyAssembly, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
              PublicKeyToken=XXXXXX, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
            <knownType type="MyCompany.Library.Circle`1,
                       MyAssembly, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                       PublicKeyToken=XXXXXX, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
                   <parameter type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2">
                      <parameter type="System.String"/>
                      <parameter index="0"/>
                   </parameter>                
            </knownType>
         </add>
      </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
  </system.runtime.serialization>
</configuration>
```

> Note the use config element
>   “parameter” with the attributes ‘type’
>   and ‘index’.