# How to deal with many, many known types in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I am just trying to convert a .Net 1.1 Remoting solution to a .Net 3.5 WCF solution.

The "KnownTypes" requirement is driving me mad.

My client and server share the same codebase so I'm not expecting to communicate with something unknown. I'm also using netTcpBinding to allow it to send in more-efficient-than-xml binary format.

However if I have lots of subclassing going on (and I do) then it seems any class that is to be sent via WCF that contains an abstract type must have all of the concrete types listed as "Known Types". I do not understand why it cannot work this out for itself: it knows every subclass.

If I have an abstract fruit class and concrete classes of apple, pear and banana then anytime a class contains reference to a "fruit" and is to be transported via WCF then I have to tell the class that apple, pear and banana are Known Types.

My code is very OO and has abstract classes and collections of abstract classes embedded within each other.

With remoting it worked it out and if it ever found a type that was not Serializable then it would simply throw an exception at runtime - apart from that it knew what it was doing.

Have I really got to add 1000s of lines of "KnownType" attributes throughout my code? Is there not a better way?

I'm almost considering staying with remoting because WCF seems so labour intensive to move to and there's always the chance that out of the hundreds of classes I'll miss a few and then sometime down the line start getting exceptions.

Anyone got round this problem or is it just an enormous overhead with WCF?

And does anyone understand WHY I would need Known Types anyway? Surely if it serializes my fruitbowl containing a collection of pears, apples and bananas it must have some way of telling which is which when it deserializes again. So I'm not sure what I've achieve by declaring them as Known Types.

This is really frustrating

Comment: Can you use shared assemblies between the client and server? a separate DLL that both sides reference that contain the datatypes in question?

Comment: To answer your secondary question of "Why KnownTypes is needed", if I wanted to add a Orange to the FruitBowl how will the client know how to create a Orange when it attempts to deserialize it? It has no code for oranges, only code for pears, apples, and bananas. You need to tell the client how to make one via KnownTypes. If you can share a DLL that contains all the types between the two systems both sides already know all they need to know and KnownTypes is nolonger needed.

Comment: The DLL containing all the "common" data structures is already shared. It is referenced in both the server and client and they both know what an apple is etc. If I had an "orange" in a different server DLL that was not shared with the client then I'd happily put up with a runtime error (as per remoting). This doesn't save me run-time errors - it's just I get a lot more for no apparently good reason

Comment: Do you have "[Reuse types in referenced assemblies](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rJdrT.png)" checked when you check your service refrence settings? If so, if you scroll the lower list do you see the shared dll in the list? If you built the proxy with `svcutil.exe` did you use `/r` or `/refrence` to include the DLL?

Comment: The proxy was built by hand (converting from older version it made more sense) - simply achieved by adding ServiceContract and OperationContract to existing interfaces - and then these interfaces implemented by new partial classes inheriting from ServiceModel.Clientbase(Of interface-type)

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976811/how-to-specify-a-wcf-known-type-in-config-that-is-generic The tag declaredTypes in dataContractSerializer allows you to put type mapping into configuration file.